# Complexity of a nested for loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I'm trying to work through various exercises in Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual." One problem that I am stuck on is as follows:

> What value is returned by the following function? Express your answer as a function of n. Give the worst-case running time using Big Oh notation.
>
> ```
> function conundrum(n)
>     r:=0
>     for i:=1 to n do
>         for j:=i+1 to n do
>             for k:=i+j-1 to n do
>                 r:=r+1
>     return(r)
> ```

My first attempt at this problem began with trying to solve it when $n$ is even and my first observation was that $r$ is never incremented for any value of $i$ greater than $n/2$ (I am assuming that a statement along the lines of "$k:=l$ to $n$" is not executed for any $l>n$. Indeed, upon working out the above function for several different values of $n$, I thought that I could intuit that the sum calculated by the function had the following form $\sum_{p=1}^{n/2}\sum_{q=1}^{2p-1}q$-- to intuit this, I began the first loop at $i=n/2$ and worked backwards. Working this sum out, I got $\frac 1 {24} n(n(2n-3)-26)$. To my dismay, upon checking this answer, I found that the correct answer for even $n$ is $\frac 1 {24} n(n+2)(2n-1)$. Any thoughts or hints about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: check if theses answers helps: [A puzzle related to nested loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13622284/1673391), and [Nested loops result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17023778/1673391)

Comment: We have [many similar questions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[algorithm-analysis]+nested+loop) already, did you look at them? Basically, don't "intuit" the sum but derive it in a structured way.

Comment: Fwiw, this question is not a duplicate. It is somewhat trickier than solutions linked in comments / closing. Real upper limits are not 'n'. So the summations need adjustments. See hint in p64 [here](https://ianparberry.com/books/free/poa.pdf)

Comment: As for the question, second summation needs to be _q=p+1_ to _n-p+1_. Obviously second summation start has to depend on _p_ and the end has to depend on _n_ in some form or other.